# Pivotal gemfire cluster configuration

Tags: java, gemfire, geode

I am trying to set up a Pivotal Gemfire cluster with two nodes/hosts. Precisely two different unix servers. The idea behind is creating 1 locator and 1 cache server in each host where the locators should take care of load balancing among the cache servers. A replicated region will be created in both the cache servers. When a client creates/update a region in cache server using gfsh or java API, it should be replicated to other one

Using gfsh, I am able to start a locator (locator 1) and a cache server (server 1) in host_A and likewise in host_B. I have created a region (RegionA) in both the servers.

Is that all i have to do ?. Pivotal tutorials talk about having a locator and multiple cache servers in same machine. I could not find any appropriate resource which talks about multi-server/host configuration.

After starting the servers in both the hosts. I am starting servers in each of the host like this.

start server --name=server1 --locators=host_A[10334],host_B[10334] --group=group1 --server-port=40406

start server --name=server2 --locators=host_A[10334],host_B[10334] --group=group1 --server-port=40406

When i do "list members" in gfsh, host B shows (locator 2, server 1 [from host A], server 2), but host A shows locator 1 only. Ideally i am expecting 2 locator s and 2 servers as members in both the machines. Is that not right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps look just fine, are you having any issues or something is not working while using the started cluster?. You can go through [Pivotal GemFire in 15 Minutes or Less](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/gemfire/getting_started/15_minute_quickstart_gfsh.html) to get to know how to start locators and servers, and how to interact with them as well. The only extra item I can think of (not mentioned withint he previous link as all members are started locally within the same `gfsh` session) is that you need to correctly configure the `--locators` parameter when starting your members, more information about how this works can be found in [How Member Discovery Works](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/topologies_and_comm/topology_concepts/how_member_discovery_works.html) and [Configuring Peer-to-Peer Discovery](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/topologies_and_comm/p2p_configuration/setting_up_a_p2p_system.html).

Just for your reference, you can have as many members as you want per host, there's no implicit limit about this other than the actual physical resources on the host itself (memory, disk, ports, network throughput, etc.). Keep in mind, however, that it is always better to have only one member per host to achieve the highest reliability and availability for both your data and locator services.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the post with what is happening. Please check and let me know if i am missing something here.

Comment: I got it working. Thanks. I had not included --locators while starting another locator in another server. After including it, it works like a charm. Please include (locators and servers) in your answer where you have mentioned about --locators parameter, which would help beginners like me to understand quickly